# Creating a MATLAB function that determines the amount of change a customer is owed after a purchase

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I have created a function in MATLAB, that displays the amount of change due (GB Currency) when the cost of an item and the amount of money given for the item are input.

```
function C = myChange(cost, paid) 
M = [50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01]; 
C = []; 
for i = 1:size(M,2) 
    if (paid - cost) >= M(i) 
        C = [M(i); myChange(cost, paid-M(i))]; 
        break 
    elseif (paid - cost) == 0 
        break 
    end 
end 
end
```

The function seems to work perfectly when integers are used,

```
>> myChange(2, 4)

ans =

     2

>> myChange(20, 32)

ans =

    10
     2
```

However, sometimes, but not all the time, when decimal points are incorporated in the inputs, the amount of change comes up one penny (cent) short

```
 >> myChange(2, 3.25)

ans =

    1.0000
    0.2000
    0.0200
    0.0200
```

In this case, though, the correct change is once again displayed

```
>> myChange(27.57, 100) 

ans =

   50.0000
   20.0000
    2.0000
    0.2000
    0.2000
    0.0200
    0.0100
```

I'm not sure what could be causing this inconsistency, having played around with the function for while now to no avail. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Besides 0.5, none of the fractional elements of `M` have an exact binary representation.

Comment: Money is fundamentally an integer quantity, so adjust your units accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: So, to make the function work, I must let £50 be represented by 5000 and 1p be represented by 1, so that all monetary values are represented by an integer?

Comment: That's almost certainly the best way to do it

Comment: Yes, that is one possible solution. An easy fix would be to add a tolerance of 0.005

Comment: You can do it internally. Multiply all user input by 100 and round in the beginning. Problem solved.